# Is there a way to maintain the MSVC function order so it appears in the same order in machine code?

Tags: c, visual-studio

I'm creating a Debug x64 project with MSVC 2019.

For example, notice the function order whereby `shellcode_start()` is first then followed by `shellcode_finish()`

```
#include <Windows.h>

void shellcode_start() {}
void shellcode_finish() {}

int main() {
    unsigned char *start = (unsigned char*)shellcode_start;
    unsigned char *finish = (unsigned char*)shellcode_finish;
    unsigned int sizeofshellcode = finish - start;
    return 0;
}
```

However, when the Debug executable is generated, the reverse occurs

**shellcode_finish:**

```
00007ff7`6af81000 4055            push    rbp
00007ff7`6af81002 4883ec40        sub     rsp,40h
00007ff7`6af81006 488bec          mov     rbp,rsp
00007ff7`6af81009 488d6540        lea     rsp,[rbp+40h]
00007ff7`6af8100d 5d              pop     rbp
00007ff7`6af8100e c3              ret
00007ff7`6af8100f cc              int     3
```

**shellcode_start:**

```
00007ff7`6af81010 4055            push    rbp
00007ff7`6af81012 4883ec40        sub     rsp,40h
00007ff7`6af81016 488bec          mov     rbp,rsp
00007ff7`6af81019 488d6540        lea     rsp,[rbp+40h]
00007ff7`6af8101d 5d              pop     rbp
00007ff7`6af8101e c3              ret
00007ff7`6af8101f cc              int     3
```

**main:**

```
00007ff7`6af81020 4055            push    rbp
00007ff7`6af81022 4883ec60        sub     rsp,60h
00007ff7`6af81026 488bec          mov     rbp,rsp
00007ff7`6af81029 488d05e0ffffff  lea     rax,[shellcode_start (00007ff7`6af81010)]
00007ff7`6af81030 48894500        mov     qword ptr [rbp],rax
00007ff7`6af81034 488d05c5ffffff  lea     rax,[shellcode_finish (00007ff7`6af81000)]
00007ff7`6af8103b 48894508        mov     qword ptr [rbp+8],rax
00007ff7`6af8103f 488b4500        mov     rax,qword ptr [rbp]
00007ff7`6af81043 488b4d08        mov     rcx,qword ptr [rbp+8]
00007ff7`6af81047 482bc8          sub     rcx,rax
00007ff7`6af8104a 488bc1          mov     rax,rcx
00007ff7`6af8104d 894510          mov     dword ptr [rbp+10h],eax
00007ff7`6af81050 33c0            xor     eax,eax
00007ff7`6af81052 488d6560        lea     rsp,[rbp+60h]
00007ff7`6af81056 5d              pop     rbp
00007ff7`6af81057 c3              ret
```

I've tried setting the linker option [Function Order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/order-put-functions-in-order?view=msvc-170) which updates the linker Command Line, but it still reversed the function order?

```
/ORDER:@"order.cpp"
```

The compile command line is

```
/permissive- /ifcOutput "x64\Debug\" /GS- /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /ZI /Gm- /Od /sdl- /Fd"x64\Debug\vc142.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /MDd /FC /Fa"x64\Debug\" /nologo /Fo"x64\Debug\" /Fp"x64\Debug\order.pch" /diagnostics:column
```

The linker command line is

```
/OUT:"C:\Users\[user]\source\repos\order\x64\Debug\order.exe" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"C:\Users\[user]\source\repos\order\x64\Debug\order.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /DEBUG /MACHINE:X64 /INCREMENTAL /PGD:"C:\Users\[user]\source\repos\order\x64\Debug\order.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"x64\Debug\order.exe.intermediate.manifest" /LTCGOUT:"x64\Debug\order.iobj" /ORDER:@"order.cpp" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /ILK:"x64\Debug\order.ilk" /NOLOGO /TLBID:1
```

**Question**

Is there any way to prevent the MSVC linker from reordering C functions in the machine code?

Years ago there was /OPT:NOWIN98 but has been deprecated. For now, I'll assume the linker reorders the functions to improve performance. Looks like GCC uses

**-fno-toplevel-reorder**

> Do not reorder top-level functions, variables, and asm statements.
> Output them in the same order that they appear in the input file. When
> this option is used, unreferenced static variables are not removed.
> This option is intended to support existing code that relies on a
> particular ordering. For new code, it is better to use attributes when
> possible.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you'd want `shellcode_start()` to be placed before `shellcode_finish()` in the binary? Before `/ORDER`, could you show the command line you use to compile ?

Comment: Probably you are missing the `/Gy` compiler flag (see [MSVC documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/gy-enable-function-level-linking?view=msvc-170))